# cats-effect: How to transform `List[IO]` to `IO[List]`

Tags: scala, io, scala-cats

I created a list of `IO[Unit]` in order to retrieve data from a list of URL. But now how I convert it back to a single `IO[Unit]` ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can do this in the following way

```
val x: List[IO[Unit]] = ???

import cats.implicits._

val y: IO[List[Unit]] = x.sequence

val z: IO[Unit] = y.map(_ => ())
```

Comment: Also, you can substitute `.map(_ => ())` with `.void` (though `sequence_` mentioned below is shorter). see the [scaladoc](https://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/Functor.html#void[A](fa:F[A]):F[Unit])

Answer (score 17):

This is just in addition to what Dmytro already said, you can actually do it in a single step by using `traverse_` or `sequence_`. Both of these are really useful if you just don't care about the result. Code would look like this:

```
import cats.implicits._

val x: List[IO[Unit]] = ???

val y: IO[Unit] = x.sequence_
```